# What is "burnout current" in an AD7730?

Tags: microcontroller, adc

There are "Burn Out" bits in the mode register. I don't see a good description in the datasheet.

How can I use these correctly?  I don't want to spoil the ADC...

Comment: Not Brown out by any chance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "burnout currents" are current sources that you can turn on and off for diagnostic purposes.  In other words, you can use them to see if your external transducer(s) have burned out :)

The circuit looks like this:

[image: burnout]

Here, from page 25 of the [datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7730_7730L.pdf): (emphasis mine)

> Burnout Currents
>   The AD7730 contains two 100 nA constant current generators,
>   one source current from AVDD to AIN(+) and one sink current
>   from AIN(–) to AGND. The currents are switched to the selected
>   analog input pair. Both currents are either on or off,
>   depending on the BO bit of the Mode Register. **These currents
>   can be used in checking that a transducer is still operational
>   before attempting to take measurements on that channel**. If the
>   currents are turned on, allowed flow in the transducer, a measurement
>   of the input voltage on the analog input taken and the
>   voltage measured is full scale, it indicates that the transducer
>   has gone open-circuit. If the voltage measured is 0 V, it indicates
>   that the transducer has gone short circuit. **For normal operation,
>   these burnout currents are turned off by writing a 0 to the BO
>   bit**. The current sources work over the normal absolute input
>   voltage range specifications.

I don't know if this is a common feature, but I know I haven't heard of it before!

Comment: Another application would be to autodetect the presence of a transducer on a channel, say if you had optional functions and/or external sensors (vs. on-board ones that will always be there if they aren't broken)